# How to force package.json to create build some files?

Tags: block-editor

I successfully created block-editor part of plugin but I have problem with my wordpress application because in build folder there is only index.js index.php files but there is not fronded.js files which are responsible for frontend.

In package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build src/frontend.js src/index.js",
    "start": "wp-scripts  start src/frontend.js src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I add that I try to create dynamic blocks

Comment: Have you run the build script? `npm run build`?

Comment: I used ```yarn  wp-scripts build ``` now after ``` yarn build ``` it created me frontend.js but still after "publish" is some error- do not want to publish it at all, is loading or sth similar.

Comment: Well if there's a problem with the actual script then that's a separate issue, and there's nowhere near enough information in this question to answer that question.